# executable jar file doesn't run on window 10

Tags: java, eclipse, window, executable-jar

so it was created from eclipse. Double click didn't work, a .bat file didn't work (it open cmd and close it immediately), i have updated java RE but nothing change. The only way to run it is to move it to C:\Users\user and open cmd and type java -jar xla.jar. I don't want to change any setting of the computer since i have to send it to my friend (this is a group project). Btw i'm on the new Fall Creator Window version.

Comment: Please check your java paths were correctly set.
Also, put the snap of error is still not solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

java -cp xla.jar com.package.name.Classname

if you have main method on a specific class..  using a batch file and then run it .. if you cannot run it by double clicking  just google and create a exe to run your batch file.

Comment: Could you be a little bit more specific? Im just a newbie so there are lots of stuff i don't know or understand

Comment: Simply keep your jar file on a specific location , create a batch file with the command you used to run using cmd , ( in my case i showed how to run the exact class which has main method ,  you can use the same method on your batch file ) then try a tool like 'f2ko'  and convert your bat file to exe , then double click on exe file  would fulfill your requirement .. ( this only applies unless you want to change settings on your windows pc )